# prevent useEffect to fire on initial render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I want to do a debounce for custom input, but my problem is I can't stop useEffect from trigger on initial render

```
import { useDebouncedCallback } from "use-debounce";

interface myInputProps {
  getValue: any;
}

const MyInput = ({ getValue }: myInputProps) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getValue(value);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <input type="text" value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [debouncedCallback] = useDebouncedCallback(value => {
    console.log(value);
  }, 1000);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyInput getValue={debouncedCallback} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-lamport-ukq70?file=/src/App.tsx

I've also tried `useLayoutEffect` but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: did you try using useRef?

Answer (score 4):

We could use useRef to keep track of if it's the first time the useEffect hook is being run.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-cerf-flkf2?file=/src/App.tsx

```
const MyInput = ({ getValue }: myInputProps) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const first = useRef(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (first.current) {
      first.current = false;
      return;
    }
    getValue(value);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <input type="text" value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
  );
};
```

Comment: It is not gonna work if you wanted it to reset the `first` on page reload/refresh. Any suggestion? like to let it to tell you that this is the first time that it rendered the component but after that as long as you have not refreshed the page it should not change it to true. But if you refreshed/reload the page it is gonna change to true. But right now it is not like that (I tested it)

Answer (score 0):

Set initial value to `undefined` and you can explicitly check for `undefined`. Once the user enter, it won't be undefined.

```
const MyInput = ({ getValue }: myInputProps) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(undefined);
  React.useEffect(() => {
   if (value === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    getValue(value);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <input type="text" value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
  );
};
```